# How to replace p tag to br using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, preg-replace

How would I replace this:

```
<p class='abc'>blah blah</p> afdads
```

With this:

```
blah blah <br/>
```

Using (vanilla?) JavaScript?

Thanks!

**Updated Content**

```
$content = $_REQUEST['content'];
$content = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>/', '', $content); // Remove the start <p> or <p attr="">
$content = preg_replace('/</p>/', '<br />', $content); // Replace the end
echo $content; // Output content without P tags
```

I would something like this...hope this time you mates have got my question.

Thankyou

Comment: Would you accept jQuery as a solution?

Comment: i have updated my question..please help guys

Comment: That’s not JavaScript, it’s PHP.

Comment: I know thats php but i want that in javacritp daniel...

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for posting this question, you're a lifesaver, GitsD.

I replaced your php function to javascript and it worked!

```
content = content.replace(/<p[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br />');
```

content would now replaced p tags with '' and /p tags with br

Answer (score 3):

You could do (if you talk about strings)

```
var str = "<p class='abc'>blah blah</p> afdads";

str = str.replace("<p class='abc'>", "");
str = str.replace("</p> afdads", " <br/>");
//str = "blah blah <br/>"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid your question isn't well-specified.  Assuming you want to do that to all p tags with that class, and you're working in a web browser environment:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; ) {
  if (paras[i].className.match(/\babc\b/)) {
    var h = paras[i].innerHTML
      , b = document.createElement('br')
      , t = document.createTextNode(h)
      , p = paras[i].parentNode
    p.replaceChild(b, paras[i])
    p.insertBefore(t, b)
  }
  else {
    i++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually meant **JavaScript** and not PHP, this would do it:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
while (ps.length) {
    var p = ps[0];
    while (p.firstChild) {
        p.parentNode.insertBefore(p.firstChild, p);
    }
    p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), p);
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

This works because the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName` is ‘live’, meaning that when we remove a `p` node from the document, it also gets removed from the list.